# CQL: formatting output for "describe"?

Tags: cassandra, formatting, cql, scylla

I'm trying to write some scripts to automate some grunt work in Scylla (a port of Cassandra), and don't know much about CQL. Is there a way to get "describe keyspaces;" to output the keyspaces one per line rather than a columnar list? Similarly, can the same be done for "describe tables;"?

Comment: Why do you need it in one line ?

Comment: Brevity of code; if my script can make cqlsh spit out nicely-formatted data it can iterate on directly, then I don't have to make calls sed/awk/etc prior to processing. However, I just discovered that bash can still intelligently interpret the "normal" output as an iterable list, so this isn't particularly necessary for my purpose.

Comment: the to string on drivers meta data will provide it. Who knows if that will work with scylla though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a backup of `keyspace names`, for example:

```
$ cqlsh <host> -u <username> -p <passwod> -e "DESC KEYSPACES" > keyspace_name_list.cql
```

Your backup in `keyspace_name_list.cql` will looks like-

```
abc def ghi jkl
mno pqr stu jhk
abd abf thi
```

Then write a loop, to print `keyspace names` one by one in a line. For example [python]:

```
file = open("keyspace_name_list.cql","r")
for line in file:
    for keyspace_name in line.split():        
        print keyspace_name
```

It will `print` your `keyspace names` one by one in a line and will looks like-

```
abc 
def
ghi
jkl
mno 
pqr 
stu 
jhk
abd
abf
thi
```

Note: You can append every `print` to a different file, if you need.